# How to understand Coroutine Process with Example in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm studying coroutine with docs and some examples.
testing some examples, I found that in same CoroutineScope it works sequentially.
For example
Below code is working sequentially.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            println("Start")
        }
    }

    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            delay(2000)
            println("World2")
        }

        launch {
            delay(1000)
            println("World1")
        }

        println("Hello")
    }

    println("Done")

}

/*
Start
Hello
World1
World2
Done
*/
```

But If I change above codes like this

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch {
        delay(1000)
        println("Start")
    }

    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            delay(2000)
            println("World2")
        }

        launch {
            delay(1000)
            println("World1")
        }

        println("Hello")
    }

    println("Done")

}

/*
Hello
Start
World1
World2
Done
*/
```

Removing first CoroutineScope, the result sequence is changed.
In My Opinion, I think this is a problem of job state, but not sure.
Is there anyone who can clarify this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coroutineScope` suspends until all its children coroutines have finished their execution. In your first case, the `coroutineScope` waits until the `launch` completes and prints `Start`, that's why you see `Start` as the first output on console.

In the second part, you removed the `coroutineScope`, so now it just launches a new coroutine and moves to the next step (`launch` doesn't suspend). Then in the `coroutineScope` you launch two other coroutines (using `launch`) and print `Hello`. That's why the `Hello` gets printed first. All other print statements are waiting for the delay to finish.

After 1 second, the first `launch` completes and prints `Start` followed by `World1` and `World2`. Now when this `coroutineScope` finishes, the program control moves to the final print statement and prints `Done`.

Comment: Thank you. I realized launch is not suspending but coroutineScope suspend sub coroutines.